# Survey Question

Tags: word-choice, expressions, participles

I have drafted an internal employee survey focused around "inclusion".

One of the questions has been vetoed incorrect by my supervisor, while I maintain that the original is grammatically correct.

Original-

> We have strong norms around listening for understanding rather than
>   criticising.

Supervisor's -

> We have strong norms around listening for understanding rather than
>   as a critic.

Am I not getting a pay rise ?

Comment: Your boss is an unthinking pedant. The entire sentence is ungainly "biz-speak" anyway, and his suggested change doesn't significantly improve things. In fact, I'd say it's a *downgrade*, since it detracts from the (perfectly valid) contextual juxtaposition of two *gerunds*. Perhaps you'll still get your pay rise if you suggest using a pair of infinitives: *...listening **in order to understand** rather than **to criticise***. But that would lose the potentially-intended nuance of *listening **in such a way as to encourage** [understanding/criticism*.

Comment: I'm afraid you're not getting a pay raise.  It's good that you and your boss are thinking critically about what you're saying.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I clearly understand the difference b/w the original, my supervisor's and your "invaluable" suggestion of using a pair of infinitives.. But was my construction grammatically incorrect?

Comment: @twothousandfifteen: All I see here is issues of "style", not "grammar". And from that perspective, the first five words are far less defensible than the last five.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary problem with

> We have strong norms around listening for understanding rather than as a critic.

is that it isn't expressed in clear parallel, which leaves the reader struggling to make sense of the comparison. The problem is exacerbated by the fact that the plural "We" at the beginning of the sentence resolves into the singular "a critic" at the end. This wording isn't wrong if "a critic" has a referent earlier in the sentence that sets up its singularity, as would be the case if you added the words given in brackets below:

> We have strong norms around [having each member of our staff] listening for understanding rather than as a critic.

In that case at least we would know who is not supposed to be acting as a critic. But as originally written, the "as a critic" sentence gives no hint of who the critic is or where he or she came from.

Your original wording finessed that issue, which I think makes it significantly better in that respect; I also think that yours is stylistically stronger in trying to present the alternatives in parallel. Unfortunately the parallelism in your wording is ambiguous. Specifically, the problem with

> We have strong norms around listening for understanding rather than criticising.

is that it leaves the reader wondering whether the intended pairing in the sentence is of "listening (for understanding)" with "criticizing" or of "listening for understanding" with "listening for criticizing." That is, it's not clear whether the intended parallel entities are *listening* and *criticizing* (on the one hand) or *understanding* and *criticizing* (on the other).

You can overcome this problem by taking the advice of FumbleFingers (and later ATHENA) to adopt parallel infinitive forms in place of the *-ing* forms. Doing so would yield (depending on what you meant to say in the first place) either

> We have strong norms around listening [in order] to understand rather than in order to criticise.

if *understanding* and *criticizing* were the intended parallel elements in the original sentence, or

> We have strong norms around listening [in order to] to understand rather than criticising [without trying to understand].

if *listening* and *criticising* were the intended parallel elements.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct, but they mean slightly different things.

The original version means:

> We have strong norms around the action of listening for understanding,
>   rather than the action of criticizing.

Your supervisor's version means:

> We have strong norms around listening with the intention of
>   understanding rather than listening as a critic.

Only you and your supervisor can decide which one you mean.

Comment: As a personal comment "Have strong norms around..." is a complex phrase that doesn't actually say which of the two options you prefer. If it was me I would use two words instead of five: "We prefer..."

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Try-

> We have strong norms around listening to understand rather than to
>   criticise.